# Normalizing Numeric Columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, normalization

I need to normalize all numeric columns of the data frame clean_mlb.

[Here is a picture of clean_mlb (Photo #1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCBv4.png)

[image: Photo #2]

[image: Photo #3]

This is the code that I wrote:

`scaled_mlb = data.frame(scale(clean_mlb))`

And this is the error that I got:

Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

Answer (score 0):

Find out columns which are numeric and then apply `scale` on those columns.

```
cols <- sapply(clean_mlb, is.numeric)
clean_mlb[cols] <- scale(clean_mlb[cols])
```